# Resize Image Content but Keep Image Dimensions

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am trying to make a basic Pokemon replica in Python using PyGame. I have followed a few tutorials concerning this library in the past. So, for this project, I will have a basic tile structure, either grass or water. The player is not allowed to move onto a water tile but can move freely on the grass tile. The sprite I obtained via the tutorial is of dimensions 64 x 64 and it occupies the entire space of the tile, so there are no transparent pixels around the boundaries.

However, for my purposes, I need to use my own sprites (64 x 64) which I got from a sprite sheet. However, the sprites, in this case, have the top half of the image as just transparent, unused pixels. The same applies to the quarters on each side of the sprite. So, I need to batch resize all those sprites by multiplying the visible pixel size by 2 along both axes. IE, just increase the sprite size by scale factor 2. I could easily do that, ***but*** it would still be ineffective since the new sprite size would be 128 x 128 and the ratio of unused pixels stays the same.

My question:

- How can I resize the sprites by scale factor 2 and yet retain the original dimensions of 64 x 64 by just disposing of the transparent pixels which would be outside of the 64 x 64 frame?

I need a method which I could use for all 9600 sprites I have, preferably in Python, even though I wouldn't mind a solution with some other software.

I tried looking for solutions on the web but I don't know how to properly phrase this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with transparent alpha and a size of 32x32:

```py
new_image = pygame.Surface((32, 32), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

[`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the desired region (32, 16, 32, 32) form the original 64x64 Sprite (`original_image`) on to the new surface:

```py
new_image.blit(original_image, (0, 0), (32, 16, 32, 32))
```

Scale the new Surface object by [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale)

```py
new_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(new_image, (64, 64))
```

Comment: I get a <Surface(32x32x32 SW)> as new_image after the "blit". However, at the next line, I get the error: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'pygame'. Also, the original_image should be a surface, right, otherwise I get the type error "pygame.Surface, not str" at the "blit" part. The first error probably has something to do with my appalling understanding of OOP.

Comment: @user12937488 Sorry, my bad. There was a mistake in the answer. I've corrected it. `new_image.pygame.transform.smoothscale(new_image, (64, 64))` has to be `new_image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(new_image, (64, 64))`

Answer (score 1):

If these are images you can easily do this using [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html).

```py
from PIL import Image
```

Ignore this bit which just makes a 64x64 test image

```py
from scipy import misc
img = misc.face()

img=Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img))
img=img.resize((64,64))
```

This should show a cute little raccoon

[image]

Next we can resize by a scale factor of two as you describe (NOTE: I'm not taking advantage of the fact that this is a square image just so this is more generalizable. You could simplify this a bit with `imsz=img.size[0]` )

```py
imsz=img.size
# resize by factor of 2
img=img.resize((imsz[0]*2,imsz[1]*2))
```

Which should give a 2x scaled image

[image]

Now we just crop it

```py
# box – The crop rectangle, as a (left, upper, right, lower)-tuple
crpimg=img.crop(box=(int(0.5*imsz[0]),int(0.5*imsz[1]),int(1.5*imsz[0]),int(1.5*imsz[1])))
```

Which gives us a 64x64 image:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer and solution. But I think the questioner asked for a solution with [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news).

Comment: Yes, this is another very good solution. I will definitely try it out alongside the accepted solution, in case I have any other issues in the future which this method could avoid. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

@Rabbid76's answer of copying/blit'ing a section of the original and then enlarging/scaling it is a good option and probably the way I would go.

However, if you have already resized them to the larger size and just want a cropped down version of an existing image/surface, you can use [subsurface()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface).  That will give you a surface that is really like a virtual surface that provides a window into a subsection of the original surface. It references the same pixels as the original surface, so if one is changed it is visible in the other as well. That does not seem an issue for what you are doing though.